# Java 8 Streams: count all elements which enter the terminal operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wonder whether there is a nicer (or just an other) approach to get the count of all items that enter the terminal operation of a stream instead of the following:

```
Stream<T> stream = ... // given as parameter
AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong();
stream.filter(...).map(...)
      .peek(t -> count.incrementAndGet())
```

where `count.get()` gives me the actual count of the processed items at that stage.

I deliberately skipped the terminal operation as that might change between `.forEach`, `.reduce` or `.collect`.
I do know [`.count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) already, but it seems to work well only if I exchange a `.forEach` with a `.map` and use the `.count` as terminal operation instead. But it seems to me as if `.map` is then misused.

What I don't really like with the above solution: if a filter is added after it, it just counts the elements at that specific stage, but not the ones that are going into the terminal operation.

The other approach that comes to my mind is to `collect` the filtered and mapped values into a list and operate on that and just call `list.size()` to get the count. However this will not work, if the collection of the stream would lead to an error, whereas with the above solution I could have a count for all processed items so far, if an appropriate `try/catch` is in place. That however isn't a hard requirement.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143020/discussion-on-question-by-roland-java-8-streams-count-all-elements-which-enter).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you already have the *cleanest* solution via `peek` before the terminal operation IMO. The only reason I could think that this is needed is for debug purposes - and if that is the case, than `peek` was designed for that. Wrapping the Stream for that and providing separate implementations is way too much - besides the huge amount of time and later support for everything that get's added to `Streams`.

For the part of *what if there is another filter added?* Well, provide a code comment(lots of us do that) and a few test cases that would otherwise fail for example.

---

Just my 0.02$

Answer (score 0):

The best idea that is possible is using a mapping on itself and while doing so counting the invocation of the mapping routine.

```
steam.map(object -> {counter.incrementAndGet(); return object;});
```

Since this lambda can be reused and you can replace any lambda with an object you can create a counter object like this:

```
class StreamCounter<T> implements Function<? super T,? extends T> {
  int counter = 0;
  public T apply(T object) { counter++; return object;}
  public int get() { return counter;}
}
```

So using:

```
StreamCounter<String> myCounter = new ...;
stream.map(myCounter)...
int count = myCounter.get();
```

Since again the map invocation is just another point of reuse the map method can be provided by extending Stream and wrap the ordinary stream.

This way you can create something like:

```
AtomicLong myValue = new AtomicLong();
...
convert(stream).measure(myValue).map(...).measure(mySecondValue).filter(...).measure(myThirdValue).toList(...);
```

This way you can simply have your own Stream wrapper that wraps transparently every stream in its own version (which is no performance or memory overhead) and measure the cardinality of any such point of measure.

This is often done when analyzing complexity of algorithms when creating map/reduce solutions. Extending your stream implementation by not taking a atomic long instance for counting but only the name of the measure point your stream implementation can hold unlimited number of measure points while providing a flexible way to print a report.

Such an implementation can remember the concrete sequence of stream methods along with the position of each measure point and brings outputs like:

```
list ->  (32k)map -> (32k)filter -> (5k)map -> avg().
```

Such a stream implementation is written once, can be used for testing but also for reporting.

Build in into an every day implementation gives the possibility to gather statistics for certain processing and allow for a dynamic optimization by using a different permutation of operations. This would be for example a query optimizer.

So in your case the best would be reusing a `StreamCounter` first and depending on the frequency of use, the number of counters and the affinity for the DRY-principle eventually implement a more sophisticated solution later on.

PS: `StreamCounter` uses an int value and is not thread-safe so in a parallel stream setup one would replace the `int` with an `AtomicInteger` instance.

Comment: There is no advantage in abusing `map` instead of using `peek`.

Comment: Simplicity by allowing to infuse actual mapping logic by stacking it on top

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what “to infuse actual mapping logic by stacking it on top” is supposed to mean. If you have an “actual mapping logic”, just use `map`. If you don’t have, don’t chain a `map` operation. How does that affect the counting `peek` operation?

Comment: Generation conflict... But in the end peek should not be used in practice. It is said to be instable function wise. So using map is way more correct in this regard. By stacking I mean that we often when using such a counter wrap the original logic: <code>stream.map(object -> convert(object)) becomes stream.map(count("name of counter", () ->  convert(object)). This method for instance is part of our test framework.

Comment: `peek` is meant to help debugging. Testing falls under this category. In contrast, the problems you can have when using `peek` for anything else, are exactly the same you will get when abusing `map` this way. Like the action passed to `peek`, the function passed to `map` may get evaluated in arbitrary order and concurrently or sometimes, never at all. It makes no difference whether you say `parallelStream().map(funcWithSideEffect).findAny()` or `parallelStream().peek(actionPerformingSideEffect).findAny()`.

Comment: Again you gain nothing while using peek. We have this map solution in a lot of things that is even used in production providing statistics for optimization and reporting. I would not feel confident using peek especially if map does the trick without any problems at all.

Comment: “does the trick without any problems” is an entirely different statement than claiming that there was an advantage of abusing `map` over using `peek`. The shortcomings are exactly the same, except that `peek` was designed for this usage, however, you can do what you want in your code and let yourself surprise what it will bring you in the future, but advertising it as a better solution than the OP already has, is a different beast.