# stream has already been operated upon or closed, even after using suplier

Tags: java, java-stream

I have below code, but gettting error:

```
Stream<BigDecimal> method(Stream<BigDecimal> in) {
    if (in == null)
        return Stream.empty();

    Supplier<Stream<BigDecimal>> supplier = () -> in;
    
    Stream<BigDecimal> s1 = supplier.get().filter(e -> e != null);
    long count = s1.count();
    

    double average = supplier.get().mapToDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue).average().orElse(Double.NaN);
    
    return supplier.get();
}
```

Error says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.<init>(AbstractPipeline.java:203)
    at java.util.stream.DoublePipeline.<init>(DoublePipeline.java:90)
    at java.util.stream.DoublePipeline$StatelessOp.<init>(DoublePipeline.java:597)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$6.<init>(ReferencePipeline.java:238)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.mapToDouble(ReferencePipeline.java:237)
```

How to fix this issue, I already tried using supplier.get method, but still getting errors.

Comment: `.count()` is a terminal operation, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/43653761/6245535 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/38044849/6245535 for more info.

Comment: @LorisSecuro, Iam getting error at mapToDouble

Answer (score 0):

You're not *really* using the `Supplier` here.  If you want this to work, the argument to `method` must *itself* be a `Supplier<Stream<BigDecimal>>`.  `() -> in` doesn't actually do what you need the supplier to do, which is to generate an entirely new stream.

Comment: Then how to perform multiple operations with my stream?

Comment: The rest of it is fine.  You just have to accept a `Supplier<Stream<BigDecimal>>` instead of a `Stream<BigDecimal>`.

Comment: I cannot change my method signature of my program, it is fixed in my case.

Comment: Then the only option you have is to collect the stream to a list or array and then to operate over that list or array.